# Displaying all connected users Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a timer that polls all connected users with discord.js.

My current code is...

```
Bot.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval (function (){
        var u = Bot.users();
        console.log(u);
    }, 10000);
});
```

However, it doesn't work with a error "TypeError: Bot.users is not a function".

I'm just not sure how this works. I've also tried...

```
Bot.server.users();
Bot.guilds.users();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=users, users is an associative array, not a function. Try:

```
Bot.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval (function (){
        var u, user;
        for(u in Bot.users){
           user = Bot.users[u];
           if(user instanceof Discord.User) console.log("["+u+"] "+user.username);
        }
    }, 10000);
});
```

EDIT: should now print out username and user id.

Comment: It's kicking back a "_array :  null
_keyArray :  null". I'm not sure what this means

Comment: Odd: try just doing `console.log(Bot.users);` and see what it says? The docs say **All of the User objects that have been cached at any point, mapped by their IDs**
**Type: Collection<Snowflake, User>** so I'd think it would be an associative array, but perhaps not. You should also make sure there are some users logged in.

Comment: Displays...
  bot: false,
  lastMessageID: null },
  '229092771175202817' => User {
  id: '229092771175202817',
  username: 'Czel',
  discriminator: '1053',
  avatar: null,
  bot: false,
  lastMessageID: null },
  _array: null,
  _keyArray: null }

Comment: Yeah, I was right, it is an associative array. Adjusted the answer to print out the id and username.

Comment: This kicks back....
/index.js:18
           if (user instanceof User) {
                               ^
ReferenceError: User is not defined

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using? Looking at https://discord.js.org/#/docs/ I'm not sure why User would not be defined.

Comment: discord.js@11.0.0, npm outdated doesn't see it as out dated.

Comment: AH, alright. Updated. I'm assuming `Bot` was created like `var Bot = Discord.Client();`?

Comment: const Bot = new Commando.Client();, but also tested it with const Bot = new Discord.Client(); and am now getting... index.js:20
           if(user instanceof Commando.User) console.log("["+u+"] "+user.username);
                   ^
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Comment: If using Commando, see https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/CommandoClient: there doesn't appear to be a way to get users. If using Discord.Client, change it to `Discord.User`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bot.on("ready", function(){
    var Count;
    for(Count in Bot.users.array()){
       var User = Bot.users.array()[Count];
       console.log(User.username);
    }

})
```

I'm still quite new to javascript, and I've also had the same problem, so I tried solving it, took me forever to figure this out but I did it anyway, hope this helps!

I didn't add the setInterval thingy but you can add it in if you want.  Basically i just added a **.array** and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to display all users' username connected to your server, online or not :

```
Bot.on('ready', () => {
   setInterval (function (){
      for (user of Bot.users){
        console.log(user[1].username);
      }       
   }, 10000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
var guilds = client.guilds;
console.log(guilds);
```

This returns a collecting which contain all the guilds which bot is connected and the guild contains its all members it gives lot of info see the cmd log

More information below:

What is guild, refer to this link:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild

What is collection, refer to this other link:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection