# How to list all members from a specific server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code is

```
const list = client.guilds.find("id", "335507048017952771")
       for (user of list.users){
         console.log(user[1].username);
       }
```

This does literally nothing. There is no error or anything.

I just want the bot to find a server and then log all members from said server.

[Displaying all connected users Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125985/displaying-all-connected-users-discord-js) The answers in this question didn't really help me at all. I did try using `message.guild.users` but that also did nothing. Can't seem to find anything on [the Discord.js site](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) to help me either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `.find("id", "335507048017952771")`, you should be using `.get("335507048017952771")`, as it says on the discord.js [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find).

> All collections used in Discord.js are mapped using their id property, and if you want to find by id you should use the get method. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) for details.

A [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) does not have a `users` property, where as it has a [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) property, which returns a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s. Now to get the [`username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username) from each member you can obtain that from the [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) property of the GuildMember. So, you will need to iterate through the collection of GuildMembers, and get the `<GuildMember>.user.username`.

There are several ways to do this, I will be using the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method. Here's what that would look like as a result:

```
// Get the Guild and store it under the variable "list"
const list = client.guilds.get("335507048017952771"); 

// Iterate through the collection of GuildMembers from the Guild getting the username property of each member 
list.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
```

Comment: this way you will get a cached version though, not the most up to date list.

Comment: how would one get the most up to date list?

Comment: you can use the method **fetch** of the **members** property.

`list.members.fetch().then(members => console.log(members))`. Please refer to the [documentation of Partials](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/topics/partials)

Comment: In my case it says that `TypeError: list.members.forEach is not a function`

Answer (score 3):

### Updated Answer

Since Discord.js v12, the `members` property of `Guild` changed from a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v11/class/Collection) to a [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager). This means you cannot iterate over it anymore like in the previous answer.

#### Using [GuildMemberManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager)

You can use the [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) property to get the member list as a collection. Note that `fetch` is an [asynchronous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and you'll have to handle it accordingly.

```
// Get the target guild
const guild = client.guilds.resolve("335507048017952771");

// Fetch the members of the guild and log them
guild.members.fetch()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

You can force discord.js to ignore the cache and query all the data from the API for the most up-to-date data, but i would not encourage it for large bots/servers.

```
// Fetch the members of the guild from the API and log them
guild.members.fetch({ force: true })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

#### Member Count

Considering that some begineers might look at this, note that `Guild` has a property named `memberCount` that allows you to get the number of members in the guild rather than fetching the list if this is what you're trying to achieve.