# How to Get a List of Members in a Guild Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to get all the members in a guild using Discord.js v12. This is what I have:

```
    const list = client.guilds.cache.get("720352141709148200");
    list.members.forEach(member => {
       //do stuff with guild memebrs here
    }
```

I have looked at this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319939/how-to-list-all-members-from-a-specific-server) but I believe it's out of date as it throws an error saying that `guilds` is undefined. This is the error I get with the modified-ish code I have above:

```
TypeError: list.members.forEach is not a function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Jakye, you need to change `list.members` to `list.members.cache`.

However, you cannot use `.forEach()`, as that's an array method and `list.members.cache` returns a Discord collection ([`Discord.Collection()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)).

Instead of `.forEach()`, you can use [`.each()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each):

```js
list.members.cache.each(member => {
  // do stuff with guild members here
});
```

Alternatively, you could convert the collection into an array of values using [`.array()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array) and then using `.forEach()` on that:

```js
list.members.cache.array().forEach(member => {
  // do stuff with guild members here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Discord JS v12, instead of `list.members.forEach()` you need to use `list.members.cache.forEach()`.