# Discord.js get all members in a guild problem

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(msg.guild.id);
guild.members.cache.each((member)=>{
  console.log(member);
});
```

logs only my id and the bots id. Anyone know the solution?

Comment: `each`? Did you mean `forEach`?

Comment: Its an object not an array so we use each instead of forEach.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answerd already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197222/how-to-get-a-list-of-members-in-a-guild-discord-js). If it still doesn't work, have you turned the gateway intents on in the [Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)?

[image: Gateway Intents]

Comment: @BlueSky That's weird, I had the same, with the bot logging only me and itself. But after turning the intents on, it worked. Btw, I tried using `.each` and `.forEach`, both worked for me..

Comment: K i will try after making the checkboxes on.